# C++ global reference vs. local variable

Tags: c++, reference

I am starter in this language and I have question: Does anybody can explain why this code works? Even if it works, Is this code "dangerous"? Is it a good practice to use global references in C++?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class v3 {
    protected:
        double t[3];
    public:
        v3(double x, double y, double z);
        void printout(void);
};

v3::v3(double x, double y , double z) {
    t[0]=x;
    t[1]=y;
    t[2]=z;
}

void v3::printout(void) {
    cout<<"(";
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) cout<<t[i]<<";";
    cout<<t[2]<<")"<<endl;
}

v3 global(3, 3, 3);
v3& globalref = global;

void copylocal2globalref(void) {
    v3 local(4, 4, 4);
    globalref = local;
}

int main()
{
    globalref.printout();
    copylocal2globalref();        
    globalref.printout();

    return 0;
}
```

I thought that the object called 'local' does not exist after the invocation of function called 'copylocal2globalref()'. But I could print out the reference which points to 'local' object! How?!? By the way Is the "reference points to an object" a good expression? It sounds like the refrence would be a pointer but it is obviously not!

Comment: youre copying local onto the global object 'through' globalref. so what youre printing isnt local but the copy you made of it in global. references are aliases to objects (i.e. they cannot be null or rebound), so when you do `globalref = local;` youre essentially saying `global = local;` so it doesnt matter if local exists or not by the time the second print happens because in both prints youre printing global.

Comment: One cannot rebind a reference. What your code does is assignment of the values from the local object to the global one. Everything's fine. Check addresses or print value of the global to see to what happens. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/719x8Tvav)

Comment: You can't reassign references; once a reference is initialised it will always refer to the same object. This line `globalref = local;` does not change the reference, it assigns to the referred object `global`.  It's equivalent to `global = local`, which copies the contents of `local` into `global`.

Comment: I'd recommend you print out some pointer addresses to see where which data is stored, and also that you explicitely define all sorts of operators and constructors on `v3`, that is especially empty constructor, copy constructor and assignment operator, and then include a print in each. You can learn a lot by seeing what is called when.

Comment: Thank you all the comments! Now I understand what my code does which is often useful :)